# swift: Images in cells

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have collectionView in ViewController. And I have 12 cells.

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 4
}    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}
```

I want to load 12 different images in cells.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    media.append(UIImage(named: "0.png")!)
    media.append(UIImage(named: "1.png")!)
    media.append(UIImage(named: "2.png")!)
    media.append(UIImage(named: "3.png")!)
    media.append(UIImage(named: "4.png")!)
    media.append(UIImage(named: "5.png")!)
    media.append(UIImage(named: "6.png")!)
    media.append(UIImage(named: "7.png")!)
    media.append(UIImage(named: "8.png")!)
    media.append(UIImage(named: "9.png")!)
    media.append(UIImage(named: "10.png")!)
    media.append(UIImage(named: "11.png")!)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

    cell.cardImageView.image = media[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

But I get `0.png`, `1.png`, `2.png` in every section.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better construct it like this

```
var media = [[UIImage]]()

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return media.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return media[section].count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

    cell.cardImageView.image = media[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

I want to load 12 different images in cells.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 media = [
    [UIImage(named: "0.png")!,UIImage(named: "1.png")!,UIImage(named: "2.png")!],
    [UIImage(named: "3.png")!,UIImage(named: "4.png")!,UIImage(named: "5.png")!],
    [UIImage(named: "6.png")!,UIImage(named: "7.png")!,UIImage(named: "8.png")!],
    [UIImage(named: "9.png")!,UIImage(named: "10.png")!,UIImage(named: "11.png")!]
 ]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I get 0.png, 1.png, 2.png in every section

Of course you do. Because that is what you are *saying* should happen.

You are saying:

```
cell.cardImageView.image = media[indexPath.row]
```

So consider what that means, for every cell:

```
Section 0, row 0: image 0
Section 0, row 1: image 1
Section 0, row 2: image 2
Section 1, row 0: image 0
Section 1, row 1: image 1
// etc.
```

You are not taking the section number into your calculations, and the row numbers repeat within each section, so you are seeing just the same three images, repeated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have 4 sections with 3 rows. So your index path will look like this:

```
section: 0 - row 0
section: 0 - row 1
section: 0 - row 2
section: 1 - row 0
section: 1 - row 1
section: 1 - row 2
```

etc.

in order to use all 12 you can do something like:

```
cell.cardImageView.image = media[indexPath.section * 3 + indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Can't wait to hear why -1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make media array to array of array of images, like below:

```
var media = [[UIImage]]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    media.append([UIImage(named: "0.png")!, UIImage(named: "1.png")!,UIImage(named: "2.png")!])
    media.append([UIImage(named: "3.png")!, UIImage(named: "4.png")!,UIImage(named: "5.png")!])
    media.append([UIImage(named: "6.png")!, UIImage(named: "7.png")!,UIImage(named: "8.png")!])
    media.append([UIImage(named: "9.png")!, UIImage(named: "10.png")!,UIImage(named: "11.png")!])
}
```

at change cellForRow method to below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

    cell.cardImageView.image = media[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var media: [[Int]] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let numberOfSections = 3
    let numberOfCells = 4
    //create array with sections, where section is array of cells
    for sectionIndex in 0...numberOfSections - 1 {
        //create section array
        media.append([])
        for cellIndex in 1...numberOfCells {
            //calculate current cell index
            let currentCell = numberOfCells * sectionIndex + cellIndex
            media[sectionIndex].append(currentCell)
        }
     }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell
    // Creating image from our media
    cell.cardImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(media[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]).png")
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Try and avoid code only answers without explanation, especially cryptic ones with poorly named variables.